# A component changes its position after being fadeIn() with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

For this component

```
<span id="uplodIsOk" class="notextoverflow" style="position: absolute; top:585px; width:40px left: 305px; z-index:1000; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:7px; color:#3bb3e0;display: none;" >La photo est charg&#233;e avec succ&#233;s ! </span>
```

I apply this jquery :

```
$("#uplodIsOk").fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
```

and when the last fadeIn happens, the div moves from `left: 305px;` to almost `left:0px;`

and in the browser console I find the property `left` is deleted from the component style
(as well as the `width`) :

```
<span id="uplodIsOk" class="notextoverflow" style="position: absolute; top: 405px; z-index: 1000; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; display: block; vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom: 7px; color: rgb(59, 179, 224);">La photo est chargée avec succés ! </span>
```

the component is supposed to maintain its position, so why it changed ? and why the left property disappear after the fadeIn?

Comment: What are you asking? Not sure I know the question...

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: Are you doing anything else? The code seems to work fine in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/fzT3S/

Comment: for me it happens in both firefox and chrome. there are only other components  with position:absolute around this component, i dont think any interaction can happens with them.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery fade animations have known issues w/r/t positioning; basically, the default on-complete code will mess with inline styles. This is another reason NOT to use inline styles; if the styles are specific to this element, you should change it by ID in your linked CSS file. Add the following to your CSS and HTML files, and you should be golden:

new HTML:

```
<span id="uplodIsOk" class="notextoverflow">La photo est charg&#233;e avec succ&#233;s ! </span>
```

new CSS:

```
#uplodIsOk {
    position: absolute;
    top:585px;
    width:40px
    left: 305px;
    z-index:50;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    color:#3bb3e0;
    display: none;
}
```

or, if you don't have a linked CSS file, you can wrap the CSS in a style tag and stick it in your header, like so:

```
<style>
#uplodIsOk {
    position: absolute;
    top:585px;
    width:40px
    left: 305px;
    z-index:50;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    color:#3bb3e0;
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: i won't try this solution (i've tried something else completely different) if anyone find this solution correct, just tell me for i mark it as the answer for this question.Cheers!